# Vue, multifilter for html table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue to take a returned object from an axios call and fill in an html table with it. I have the table exactly as I want but I'm wondering if there's a way (don't want to convert this whole thing to datatables) to make each header a filter for the table so that multiple columns can be filtered for the whole table. Basically, say the rows have items like 'Truck', 'Trailer' and 'Container' for the 'Resources' column. I'm thinking of a dropdown filter on the header of that column that would show rows for all resources or I could select 'Truck' so that only rows with 'Truck' show on the table.

Does that make sense? Is there an inherent way to do this with Vue?

```
<table style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Resource</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody  v-for="dateEvent in dateEvents">
    <tr>
        <td v-if="dateEvent.id === '2'">{{ dateEvent.title }}</td>
        <td v-if="dateEvent.id === '2'">{{ dateEvent.resource }}</td>
        <td v-if="dateEvent.id === '2'">{{ dateEvent.location }}</td>
        <td v-if="dateEvent.id === '2'">{{ dateEvent.status }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



data () {
return {
    dateEvents: []
},
created() {
    this.fetchItems();
},
methods: {
    fetchItems() {
        axios.get('/home/resource_items')
        .then(response => {
          // handle success
          console.log(response.data)
          this.dateEvents = response.data
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
        .finally(function() {})
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `computed` functionality to automatically calculate:

- a filtered array of `dateEvents` to display in the table
- an array of `titles` to display in the filter
- an array of `resources` to display in the filter
- an array of `locations` to display in the filter
- an array of `statuses` to display in the filter

Here is an example:

```
...

<select v-model="filters.title">
  <option v-for="title in titles" :value="title">{{ title }}</option>
</select>

<select v-model="filters.resource">
  <option v-for="resource in resources" :value="resource">{{ resource }}</option>
</select>

<select v-model="filters.location">
  <option v-for="location in locations" :value="location">{{ location }}</option>
</select>

<select v-model="filters.status">
  <option v-for="status in statuses" :value="status">{{ status }}</option>
</select>

<button @click="reset">Reset</button>

...

  <tbody v-for="dateEvent in filtered">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ dateEvent.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ dateEvent.resource }}</td>
      <td>{{ dateEvent.location }}</td>
      <td>{{ dateEvent.status }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

...


...

data() {
  return {
    dateEvents: [],
    filters: {
      title: null,
      resource: null,
      location: null,
      status: null,
    },
  };
},


computed() {

  filtered() {
    return this.dataEvents
      .filter(dataEvent => !this.filters.title || dataEvent.title === this.filters.title),
      .filter(dataEvent => !this.filters.resource || dataEvent.resource === this.filters.resource),
      .filter(dataEvent => !this.filters.location || dataEvent.location === this.filters.location),
      .filter(dataEvent => !this.filters.status || dataEvent.status === this.filters.status);
  },

  titles() {
    return this.dataEvents
      .map(dataEvent => dataEvent.title)
      .filter((title, index, self) => self.indexOf(title) === index);
  },

  resources() {
    return this.dataEvents
      .map(dataEvent => dataEvent.resource)
      .filter((resource, index, self) => self.indexOf(resource) === index);
  },

  locations() {
    return this.dataEvents
      .map(dataEvent => dataEvent.location)
      .filter((location, index, self) => self.indexOf(location) === index);
  },

  statuses() {
    return this.dataEvents
      .map(dataEvent => dataEvent.status)
      .filter((status, index, self) => self.indexOf(status) === index);
  },
},


methods: {

  reset() {
    this.filters.title = null;
    this.filters.resource = null;
    this.filters.location = null;
    this.filters.status = null;
  },

},

...
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! But I do have a question: How can I keep this and just add an option to reset the select? Like if I chose 'Red' and only showed records with red but then wanted to effectively remove red and show all records again

Comment: I updated the code above, added `<button>` element and `methods` section with `reset()` method.